# Add price columns in a text file to show total

Tags: php

need some assistance. I have a text file containing products that a customer selects to purchase. I just want to know how would I add all values in specific columns from up to down.

Example of text file.

40" Non Commercial LED Monitor (Hisense);1;4735.00;4440.00;4175.00;4055.00

Software Licence Fee - 1 year;1;1155.00;1155.00;1155.00;1100.00

So as you can see there are six columns. I want to add all the values in those columns. Eg: Column 3 will add up to (4735.00+1155.00)=5890.00.

Please help.

Comment: explode(';'... and use needed column of array

Comment: Explode with ";" and sum the numbers in the array and rebuild the new string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps involved are:

1. Get the contents of file in the variable. You can use file_get_contents or fread.
2. Get all lines in array.
3. Get all separate data of lines in array
4. Total the price using the separated data.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$File_Contents = file_get_contents("test.txt");

$All_Lines = array();
if (preg_match("/\n/", $File_Contents)){
    $All_Lines = explode("\n", $File_Contents); //separate by lines
}else{
    $All_Lines[] = $File_Contents; //contains only one line;
}

$Total_Price = 0;
if (count($All_Lines) != 0 AND trim($File_Contents) != ""){
    foreach($All_Lines as $Line){
        $Line = trim($Line); //remove whitespace
        if ($Line != ""){
            $Separators = explode(";", $Line); //now you can access the separators using $Separators[0],[1]
            if (isset($Separators[2]) AND is_numeric($Separators[2])){
                $Price = $Separators[2];
                $Total_Price += $Price;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<b>Total Price:</b> {$Total_Price}";
}else{
    echo "No data";
}
?>
```

Comment: You are champion. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

And the same, but easier

```
$col_num = 2;

$arr = array_map(function($v) { return explode(';', $v); }, file("test.txt"));
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, $col_num));
```